# npm install task taking too long to start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, tfs, tfsbuild

npm install task on TFS 2017 build definition is taking too long to start on Ubuntu build agent:

```
2018-01-12T08:09:05.2269721Z [command]/usr/bin/npm install
2018-01-12T08:11:39.9810116Z npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g
2018-01-12T08:11:43.0553293Z 
2018-01-12T08:11:43.0578286Z > node-sass@4.7.2 install /home/johnny/myagent/_work/9/s/node_modules/node-sass
2018-01-12T08:11:43.0601546Z > node scripts/install.js
```

I would like to know what might be causing npm to taking 3 mins to start.As it shows, it starts at **08:09:05** the first callback is after 3 mins **08:11:39**

Comment: Try `npm install --verbose` (which provides a more verbose output), check the output for any problems. If further help is needed, please paste the verbose output in the question.

Comment: Did the build task  completes successfully ? And did you get the same behavior if use other npm commands in TFS build pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this behavior only occurs on `NPM install` command, it is make sense. NPM install is just wasting time because it takes 3-4 minutes to  **determine the packages are already installed or not.**

Try to run you npm from the console to see the performance on TFS is normal or not. If all of your NPM tasks are taking long time, one possibility is related to nodejs version.

For instance, you are using a latest version such as nodejs (8.x.0) installed on the build agent. Then downgrade to the latest LTS (long term support) version (6.11.1) may resolve the issue for you. Details please have a look at this [blog](https://writeabout.net/2017/07/31/fix-slow-performance-of-npm-tasks-on-tfs-build-agent/).

---

Another way is using [npm-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache) by **caching previously installed dependencies** on the build machine if you didn't perform build agent clean.

> It is useful for build processes that run [npm|bower|composer|jspm]
>   install every time as part of their build process. Since dependencies
>   don't change often, this often means slower build times. npm-cache
>   helps alleviate this problem by caching previously installed
>   dependencies on the build machine. npm-cache can be a drop-in
>   replacement for any build script that runs [npm|bower|composer|jspm]
>   install.
>
> **How it Works**
>
> When you run npm-cache install [npm|bower|jspm|composer], it first
>   looks for package.json, bower.json, or composer.json in the current
>   working directory depending on which dependency manager is requested.
>   It then calculates the MD5 hash of the configuration file and looks
>   for a filed named .tar.gz in the cache directory ($HOME/.package_cache
>   by default). If the file does not exist, npm-cache uses the system's
>   installed dependency manager to install the dependencies. Once the
>   dependencies are installed, npm-cache tars the newly downloaded
>   dependencies and stores them in the cache directory. The next time
>   npm-cache runs and sees the same config file, it will find the tarball
>   in the cache directory and untar the dependencies in the current
>   working directory.

A sample for your reference: [Speed up your npm dependent CI build](http://wp.sjkp.dk/speed-up-your-npm-dependent-ci-build/)